# Conservation laws for particle in an axisymmetric electromagnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, symmetry, conservation-laws, plasma-physics

I have a massive particle moving with position $X = X(t)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ and "velocity" $V = V(t)\in \mathbb{R}^3$, which satisfy the ODEs

$$\begin{align} \dot{X} &= \hat{V}\\ \dot{V} &= K(t,X,V) \end{align}$$

Where $\hat{V} = \frac{V}{\sqrt{1+|V|^2}}$ is the relativistic velocity and $K(t,X,V) = E(t,X)+\hat{V}\times B(t,X)$ is the Lorentz force (setting $m=c=q=1$ for simplicity). They can be written in potential form:

$$E = -\nabla \phi-\partial_t A$$
$$B = \nabla\times A$$

Where $\phi, A$ are given functions of $t$ and $x$, satisfying inhomogeneous Maxwell's equations with some forcing.

My question regards the kind of conservation laws one can derive if some kind of symmetry in the $x$ variable is imposed on the potentials. For example, if $\phi$ and $A$ are independent of $x_3$, i.e. $\partial_3 A = \partial_3 \phi = 0$, then a straightforward calculation shows

$$\begin{align} \frac{d}{dt}[V_3(t) + A_3(t,X(t))] &= E_3 + \hat{V}_1 B_2 - \hat{V}_2B_1 + \partial_t A_3 + \hat{V}\cdot\nabla A_3 \\ &= \big(-\partial_3 \phi-\partial_t A_3\big) + \big(\hat{V}_1\partial_3A_1-\hat{V}_1\partial_1A_3 - \hat{V}_2\partial_2 A_3 + \hat{V}_2\partial_3A_2\big) + \partial_t A_3 + \hat{V}\cdot\nabla A_3\\ &= 0\end{align}$$

Alternatively, one could impose symmetry on $A$ only and use the temporal/Weyl gauge $\phi = 0$ to obtain the same result. This of course implies that

$$V_3 + A_3 = \text{constant along the particle trajectory} \tag{*}$$

My question is this:

> If one instead imposes that $A,\phi$ are symmetric around the $x_3$ axis, can one obtain a similar conservation law, such as $R(V_{\theta}+A_{\theta})=$ const, or something similar to (*), possibly with some special fixed gauge?

To be precise, if I use cylindrical coordinates $e_{R(t)}, e_{\theta(t)}, e_3$ adapted to the particle,

$$e_{R(t)} = \frac{1}{R(t)}\left(X_1(t),X_2(t),0\right), \ R(t) = \sqrt{X_1(t)^2+X_2(t)^2}\\
e_{\theta(t)} = e_3\times e_{R(t)}\\
e_3 = (0,0,1)$$

Then *without* the use of the assumption $\partial_{\theta} A = \partial_{\theta}\phi = 0$, I found that

$$ \frac{d}{dt}[R(V_{\theta}+A_{\theta})] = R\partial_R(\phi-\hat{V}\cdot A)+(\hat{V}\times A)_3$$

Since this doesn't contain angular derivatives of the potentials, it seems unlikely that imposing cylindrical symmetry would cause this to vanish. There also doesn't seem to be a place where imposing some gauge condition would help. However, I thought it was interesting that a derivative that's effectively in an angular direction can be written as a radial derivative of the potential energy plus another component.

If I impose cylindrical symmetry on $A,\phi$, are there other similar quantities to (*) that I could hope to be conserved along the particle trajectory?

---

For additional context, the ODEs I presented above are actually the characteristic flow of the [Vlasov-Maxwell system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vlasov_equation). I'm interested in solutions when the initial distribution of particles and the electromagnetic fields are cylindrically symmetric.